# How to download sapi5 voices in Pop OS?

Tags: python, windows, pop-os, text-to-speech

I made a **python desktop assistant in windows** which took user input and gave out output in the form of speech with the help of pyttsx3 , I used one of the male voices which comes in by default in windows sapi5. Recently I shifted to Linux( Pop OS) and I found out that sapi5 isnt supported in Linux . How can i **download the windows sapi5 voices in Pop OS** .